# i want to retrieve data from MySQL db by displaying it using table, arrange it the same way it appear in the image

Tags: php, mysql

[image: img]

```
<?php




$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","shady");


    $query = "SELECT * fROM hall1  "; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());

echo "<form action='food.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table >";

$size = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 

$imagewidth=200;

if($size > 900)

{
echo"<tr>";
}

echo'<td width='.$td3=100 .'px >  </td>' ;
echo'<td width='.$td1=200 .'px> <label><input type="radio"  name="radii" value='.$row[1].' checked> <img src="'.$row['image'].'" width="200" height="200" style="margin-top:10px;"> </label></td>' ; 


echo"<td width=".$td2=200 ."px> Name &nbsp: " .$row[1]  ."<br> Size &nbsp &nbsp : ".$row[2]  ."Person <br> Price &nbsp &nbsp: ".$row[3]  ." SDG <br> <a href=see.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "> See More </a> </td>";


$size+= $imagewidth+$td1+$td2+$td3;
if($size > 900)

{
echo"<tr>";
}

} 

echo"</table>";

echo "<BR><BR><BR><CENTER><input type='submit'  name='radiii' value='next' width='200PX' height='200PX' ></a> </CENTER></b>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to retrieve data from MySQL db by displaying it using table, arrange it the same way it appear in the image ?  in the code that i tried ,   it displaying only the first row but when it come to the next it showing only one image in row till it finish

Comment: Development questions are off-topic here, your question will be migrated or closed.  However, you might want to reset $size=0 when you end a row, then delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

1. It's unclear what the variable `size` does. I'm willing to bet it's unnecessary
2. You are using deprecated code. The `width` attribute on HTML elements is no longer supported, and if you insist on using it, you should only enter the width in pixels without the `px` like so: `<td width="200">`. The `<center>` tag is also deprecated.
3. Your `<label>` tag is pretty much useless. What are you trying to achieve with it?
4. It's a bad practice to set the widths on all rows, just set the widths on the first row's cells. Even better, do not use any style directly on the HTML tags and using CSS rules instead.
5. Lastly, i believe it would be much more readable code to NOT `echo` HTML and instead use the following approach to "plug in" your variables from PHP into HTML code :

   ```
    <? $a = "Some variable"; $b = 123; $c = "http://example.com/img/1.png"; ?>
    <p><strong>My variable a: <?=$a?></p>
    <p><strong>My variable b: <?=$b?></p>
    <p><strong>My img: <img src="<?=$c?>"></p>
   ```

In short, wrap your PHP logic in `<?` and `?>` (be sure to have `short_open_tag = On` in your PHP settings or you'll need to use the alternative opening tag `<?php` like you did.

The write plain old HTML without all the `echo`. Whenever you want to echo something you simply write a new PHP opening tag like so :
`<? echo $a ?>` 
OR, the shorthand version
`<?=$a?>`

Now your real problem is about designing the page. And i think you are starting in the wrong order. I would suggest you
1- Build a design that works using some IDE like `Adobe Dreamweaver` or a freeware alternative. With that tool, make the design for 1 item (1 iteration of your while loop).

The next step is to see how you're gonna repeat it. You seem to want a Horizontal list that wraps around lines at a certain width. One way you would do that is that you would wrap all the list items with a `div` element for which you will set a fixed width. And inside you will have the code you have for each item repeated for all items. If your outer `div` has a width of 900px and each element consumes `300px` in width and you have 9 items, you would have a 3x3 grid.

Here is a summary code of what i explained. In your PHP file you would have:

```
<div class="grid">
  <? while($row = .... ){ ?>
  <div class="item">
      <!-- The code for the image, label and whatever information you want to have for each item -->
  </div>
  <? } ?>
</div>
```

And a CSS file which you would link in your PHP file, containing:

```
.grid {
    width: 900px;
}

.item {
    width: 300px;
}
```

If the information your are displaying come from user input you should sanitize it and have some sort of logic that breaks long text, either with CSS or PHP.

In short, you seem to be doing all the math in PHP so that you jump into a new line once the total width exceeds your desired grid width. This is a design issue and not a logic / programming issue. Therefore you should tackle this with CSS and not PHP.

I strongly suggest you either follow a video tutorial (there are plenty online) or read some documentations on HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP and MySQL in that order.

Here is a link to get you started: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)